# Add context during mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a class with a collection of `Thing`s, that can be identified by their `Id` in combination with their `ThingCollectionId`.

The corresponding `DtoThing` only contains the `Id` and I would like to load the `PropertyNotInDto` property from the globally known `ThingCollections` class when mapping `DtoThing` to `Thing`.

This can be achieved with an `IMappingAction` on the `DtoMyClass` to `MyClass` mapping, but this requires me to rebuild the List of Things and adds the mapping code to `MyDtoClass` instead of `DtoThing`.

```
// sources for mapping
public class MyClass {
    public Guid ThingCollectionId {get;set;}
    public Dictionary<Thing, MyClassB> Things {get;set;}
}
public class Thing {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    // other properties
    public string PropertyNotInDto {get;set;}
}
// targets for mapping
public class DtoMyClass {
    public Guid ThingCollectionId {get;set;}
    public Dictionary<DtoThing, DtoMyClassB> Things {get;set;}
}
public class DtoThing {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    // no other properties are saved in the DtoThing class
}
// global
public class ThingCollections {
    public Dictionary<Guid, List<Thing>> ThingCollections {get;}
}
```

Is there a way to add `ThingCollectionId` to a context, that can be used when the mapping code for `DtoThing` to `Thing` is used?

My imaginary syntax would look something like this:

```
 CreateMap<DtoThing, Thing>().AdvancedMapping<ThingMappingAction>();
```

where `ThingMappingAction` has access to the `ThingCollectionId`.

My current approach looks like this:

```
CreateMap<DtoMyClass, MyClass>().AfterMap<MyClassMappingAction>();
...
public MyClassMappingAction : IMappingAction<DtoMyClass, MyClass> {
    private ThingCollections ThingCollections {get;}
    public MyClassMappingAction(ThingCollections thingCollections){
       ThingCollections = thingCollections;
    }
    public void Process(MyDtoClass source, MyClass target) {
        // fix target.Things with ThingCollectionId, Thing.Id and ThingCollections
    }
}
```

But this gets especially annoying, because `Thing` is used in more than one property and requires special code for every such instance, that needs to get added to the `MyClassMappingAction`.

Comment: Try [this](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper) instead of AfterMap.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thank you for the suggestion! I am still figuring out how to set that context in the mapping profile instead of at the call to `Mapper.Map`.

Comment: The context is for the map call. For other situations you can use DI, or simply pass values when constructing the resolver instance in your mapping profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this by adding `ThingCollectionId` to the context in `BeforeMap` and using `ITypeConverter<DtoThing, Thing>` to access it again.

```
CreateMap<DtoMyClass, MyClass>().BeforeMap((dto, myclass, context) => context.Items["ThingCollectionId"] = dto.ThingCollectionId);
CreateMap<DtoThing, Thing>().ConvertUsing<ThingTypeConverter>();

public ThingTypeConverter: ITypeConverter<DtoThing, Thing> {
    private ThingCollections ThingCollections {get;}
    public MyClassMappingAction(ThingCollections thingCollections){
       ThingCollections = thingCollections;
    }
    public Thing Convert(DtoThing source, Thing destination, ResolutionContext context) {
        // Get the correct ThingCollection by ThingCollectionId
        var thingCollection = ThingCollections[(Guid)context.Items["ThingCollectionId"]];
        // Get the correct Thing from the ThingCollection by its Id
        return thingCollection.First(t => t.Id == source.Id);
    }
}
```

This replaces the `AfterMap` call and the `MyClassMappingAction` that were previously used. This way the mapping code a for `Thing` is not contained in a mapping for `MyClass` and there is no more need to manually recreate the `MyClass.Things` Dictionary.